# Left Navigation menu missing in all SharePoint 2019 sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, left-navigation

The left navigation menu disappeared from my SharePoint 2019 servers (2 Web Front Ends and 2 SQL Back Ends, all with the latest OS, SharePoint, and SQL patches) recently. I've tried the following:

1. Create a new Site Collection in the existing Web Application
2. Create a new web application and a new site collection within it

All show the same issue.

For reference, I've placed a screenshot below showing the blank left nav. To generate that screenshot, I created a new web application, created a new site collection in it (team site) and nothing else.

I welcome ideas as I am new to SharePoint 2019. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the console/network tabs in your browser for errors? Presumably you would have some failed web requests, where SharePoint is trying to load the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by an old JavaScript file being cached in the browser. Please find the below article and follow the steps.

[Solve Left Navigation Missing Issue In SP 2019](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2022/05/31/trending-issue-left-navigation-missing-after-applying-may-2022-cu-for-sharepoint-server-2019/)

I hope this will fix your issue, if so please do mark this as the answer.

Thank you...